# Is it ever appropriate to ask the same question in ELU and ELL?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155995/what-does-the-main-entrance-is-around-the-back-of-the-building-mean) appears on both ELL and on [ELU, but not as a migration](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429957/what-does-the-main-entrance-is-around-the-back-of-the-building-mean). I'm not convinced that it's really appropriate for either, but I'm also not able to articulate why, or certain enough of my judgement to flag it. However, I am fairly sure that it's not appropriate to post the same question on both. Where should it be flagged, and for what reason? Or, should the dual posting just be ignored?

Also, should I be asking this question on MetaELU instead/also?

Comment: Meta link that might be helpful: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/) Tom has deleted the duplicate post at this point (and added a dictionary definition to the EL&U one). This is still a good discussion to have even though the specific examples have changed.

Comment: Ironically, this Meta-Q has already been asked on Meta.ELU: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5302/55623 .

Comment: @DanBron I think meta duplicates are different from main site duplicates though - mostly because the communities are different and may have different answers to the same question about how the site should work.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree. This meta-Q is totally fine here. I was just responding to his sub-question “Also, should I be asking this question on MetaELU also?”.